# Want to filter SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I am  pulling out the `Facilities` where the `permitType` is `'Hazardous waste'` and the `licenseStatus` is `'Open'`, but there will be cases where the facilities will have more than one permit type suppose a facility can have two permit types

1. Hazardous waste (status - OPEN)
2. AST (OPEN)

so I should not display this facility in my output if it other permit types (Status - OPEN) apart from the 'hazardous waste', but if the other permit type has status - CLOSE then my query should output the Facility i.e if AST(Status - CLOSE) then the facility should be pulled from the database.

I wrote the following query but not sure where to include the condition.

```
SELECT  
   e.facilityID
   ,f.organization_core AS 'Facility Name'
   ,f.address_full_core AS 'Facility Address'
   ,a.permitNumber AS 'Permit Number'
   ,b.permitName AS 'Permit Name'
   ,a.licenseStatus AS 'Permit Status'
   ,c.permitType AS 'Permit Type'
FROM 
   tblPermits a
LEFT JOIN 
   dbo.tblPermit_Names b ON a.permitID = b.permitID
LEFT JOIN  
   dbo.tblLKP_Permit_Facilities d ON a.permitID = d.permitID
LEFT JOIN 
   dbo.tblPermit_Types c ON a.permitTypeID = c.permitTypeID
LEFT JOIN 
   dbo.tblFacility e ON d.facilityID = e.facilityID
LEFT JOIN 
   dbo.tblAddresses f ON e.facilityAddressID = f.addressID
WHERE   
   a.permitTypeID IN (SELECT permitTypeID 
                      FROM dbo.tblPermit_Types 
                      WHERE permitType IN ('Hazardous Waste'))
   AND a.licenseStatus = 'Open'
   AND isNull(a.deleted, 0) = 0
```

Comment: I'm confused by what conditions you are looking for.  Is it:
  If facility has a hazardous waste permit with status open it is included
  If it also has a AST(open) it should not display
  If it has AST(closed) instead it should display

So you only want facilities where Hazardous waste (open) is the only permit?

Comment: Also, a clear representation of your table structure would help

Comment: You got it correct, I want facilities with hazardous waste (Open) and any other permit such as AST(Close). If the facility has only Hazardous permit and that is open then its fine I am able to fetch that data, the problem comes when the same facility has other permit and I have to decide based on the OPEN or CLOSE of the other permit whether to display the facility of not.

Comment: tblPermits has permitID,permitNumber,permitTypeID,licenseStatus

Comment: dbo.tblLKP_Permit_Facilities has permitID,facilityID

Comment: out of curiosity, do you need to left outer join?  Seems like for this several of these would be inner joins

Comment: dbo.tblPermit_Types has permitTypeID and PermitType here the permitType includes the name such as 'Hazardous waste', 'AST' and the permitTypeID contains the code such as 1, 2,etc etc

Comment: even I though the same could please help me further. I am totally confused

Comment: Can you post the table structure for these tables?

Comment: tblPermits has permitID,permitNumber,permitTypeID,licenseStatus 
dbo.tblLKP_Permit_Facilities has permitID,facilityID
dbo.tblPermit_Types has permitTypeID and PermitType here the permitType includes the name such as 'Hazardous waste', 'AST' and the permitTypeID contains the code such as 1, 2,etc etc

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query implements your rules.  The idea is to focus on the facility and not on all the extra stuff in the tables that you have put in.  You need to aggregate by `facilityid` so you can apply logic to all the permits issued for each one:

```
SELECT f.facilityID
FROM dbo.tblFacility f join
     dbo.tblLKP_Permit_Facilities pf
     on pf.facilityID = f.facilityId join
     tblPermits p
     on pf.permitID = p.permitID join
     dbo.tblPermit_Types pt
     ON pt.permitTypeID = p.permitTypeID
GROUP BY f.facilityID
HAVING SUM(case when pt.permitType IN ('Hazardous Waste') and p.licenseStatus = 'Open'
                then 1 else 0
           end) > 0 and
       SUM(case when pt.permitType NOT IN ('Hazardous Waste') and p.licenseStatus = 'Close'
                then 1 else 0
           end) > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause is applying one of your rules.

Comment: I am sorry Gordon this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: I want facilities with hazardous waste (Open) and any other permit such as AST(Close). If the facility has only Hazardous permit and that is open then its fine I am able to fetch that data, the problem comes when the same facility has other permit and I have to decide based on the OPEN or CLOSE of the other permit whether to display the facility of not.

Comment: @jeetu . . . That is easily expressed using the same methodology.  Look at the edit.

Comment: Thank You. SUM(case when pt.permitType NOT IN ('Hazardous Waste') and p.licenseStatus = 'Close'
                then 1 else 0
           end) > 0

Comment: SUM(case when pt.permitType NOT IN ('Hazardous Waste') and p.licenseStatus = 'Close'
                then 1 else 0
           end) > 0
the '>' condition isn't puling back any data .

Comment: Now if I want to include the other parameters then what should I do.

Comment: other parametrs in the select statement which I mention in my original query

Comment: @jeetu . . . Use this as a subquery and join in any other fields you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to your table structure, but this is what I think you should do.

Your where statement should be id in (Select id from table where status = open and count(id) = 1 group by facility)
AND Type in ('Hazardous Waste')

The first part of the where statement will limit all ids to those that are open with only one open type per facility, the second part limits it to just hazardous waste.

If you have a facility with 10 permits, but only one is active, it will pull it into the list, but if the active permit isn't hazardous waste, it will then exclude it.

Sorry I can't give you exact code.

Also, nix as many of those outer joins as you can.  Inner joins are faster, and are more likely to represent the data you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
But what I want is if a facility has 10 permits and if two are active, one of them is hazardous and the other one is something else which is also active. So in this case I dont want the facility to be there in the query output.

Comment: If there are more than 1 active permits, it excludes it (or it should if I have my pseudo-syntax right).  Play around with it, this will get you close